# How do I save all notifications from a device in the background using expo-notifications in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo-notifications

I'm coding in react native and I want to save all notifications to my app even when the app itself is closed. I want to get all of the notifications and store them in the app so that users can check to see their notifications in case they missed them.

I'm using react native to code this. I currently set up a way to send notifications to the phone using expo-notifications. But the only problem is getting the notifications and saving them to the app itself. Can someone help me?

I would share my code but I feel as though it would be unhelpful. Can someone just point me to where I can find the solution to my issue?

Comment: Have you solved your issue?